# Should I check sequence length if I pass this sequence as an argument?

Tags: c#, constructor, initialization

I am implementing a struct called `Position`, which represents a geographic position containing properties `double Latitude, Longitude, Elevation`.

One of its constructors is

```
public Position(double lat, double lon, double elev)
```

and I created another like this:

```
public Position(IEnumerable<double> coords) : this(
    coords.ElementAt(0),
    coords.ElementAt(1),
    coords.ElementAt(2)
) {}
```

This is working, but somewhat it seems "wrong" that I could pass an `IEnumerable` with any length above 3, so my questions are:

1. Should I check the length of `coords` and only accept if `coords.Count == 3`?
2. Should I use a sequence type other than `IEnumerable<double>`?
3. Should I forget about passing a sequence as argument altogether, and why?

Comment: It just seems like a bad interface: a position *could* be constructed from an appropriately-sized sequence, but it doesn't actually make much sense. Make the owner of the enumerable extract the correct values if they want to use it, and keep your class clean.

Comment: 1. Yes; 2. Depends on what you want to pass to it; 3. See (2), you should think about how you want it to be used. If you know that it won’t be used way X, you don’t need to implement X.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited for [CodeReview.StackExchange.Com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @ErikPhilips I think this is probably too minimal for CR

Comment: @BenAaronson How would it then not be to minimal for here?

Comment: @ErikPhilips For example, Code Review generally doesn't consider SSCCEs on topic ( http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1916/are-sscces-off-topic ), whereas on SO they're encouraged.

Comment: Do you have an actual requirement to pass an `IEnumerable<>`?

Comment: @BenAaronson this doesn't appear to be an example, it appears to be his actual code.

Comment: @Enigmativity I am exercising myself by developing a pet project (GpsDataModel library) in parallel, in C# and Python. My plan is to have as much as an "implementation-agnostic API" for the classes, and in Python it's very common to pass arguments separately or in a sequence, so I thought about doing that both in Python and in C#, but that is not an absolute requirement (my the answers here, by the way, I am already doubting this would be a good idea even in Python in the first place...)

Comment: @ErikPhilips, Even if its on-topic for CodeReview, the question isn't "Review this file/class/function" its "Is it a good idea to initialize separate data members with a collection?" I don't see why it would be off-topic here (other than *maybe* opinon-based, but the answer seems pretty definitive)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: reading it again I find 2/3 is op-based and you can't really call it anything else than code review; it works as expected. This -> "This is working, but somewhat it seems "wrong" that I could pass an IEnumerable with any length above 3, so my questions are:" is pretty on topic for CR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you should check the length and throw an exception (probably `ArgumentException`) if it is wrong, since that is clearly an exceptional situation.
2. There isn't any type where the length is part of the type signature. However, you should use an `IList` so that order is guaranteed (unlike `IEnumerable`), and you can access by index.
3. You should forget about passing as an `IEnumerable` for exactly the reason you described. It's just an unneeded potential source of error, plus it makes your signature less descriptive, and so makes your code less readable. If you can prevent a bug at compile-time, why pass that up?

   However, you might consider creating a `Coordinates` class which just holds `Latitude`, `Longitude` and `Elevation` paramters. This may also provide useful later if you need to do something like transform to a different coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, with `Position` my goal is just to hold the named coordinates. It already does what you suggested for a `Coordinate` class to do.

Answer (score 2):

1. This will break if you have less than 3 elements in the collection, and will ignore any elements past the third if there are more. You should at least check the min condition. However, what will you do with the error, throw an exception? This speaks to why this probably isn't a good idea.
2. That is the correct parameter for generic collections.
3. Yes, as you pointed out, the number of arguments is very important to your object. Allowing a collection removes that constraint, and puts errors into run-time instead of compile-time. There isn't any advantage I can see to allowing the collection constructor.

Answer (score 2):

I would actually not pass the `IEnumerable` either (agreeing with others). If you could use the sequence to represent a Position, then why do you need to create the Position struct in the first place? You can just use `IEnumerable` in all the places in your code, can't you? :-)

One important principle of software is to implement what is needed. Do you actually have `IEnumerble` in your code elsewhere that represent position? If not, then skip this constructor, and add it only when it's needed. However, if you have such a need, then add a check for the count of arguments being not exactly 3 to avoid coding errors, which may still occur if the coordinates or elevation come in a different order than what you expected.

In your case, Position seems to be the structure that should be instantiated, either through the constructor, e.g.

```
Position p = new Position(1, 2, 3);
```

or by initializing the properties, e.g.

```
Position p = new Position
{
    Latitude = 1,
    Longitude = 2,
    Elevation = 3
};
```

Comment: Your rationale is very interesting. I created a Position class exactely for crystalizing coordinates as a typed object as soon as the data is available, so this information will be passed around other, higher-level structures in my code _already_ typed. Its constructor will be called as soon as data is made available, usually by reading a file, reading a sensor, or clicking on a map.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with other respondents here - this constructor seems like it could lead to problems as it doesn't clearly document the number of double values required.

However, if you *need* to do this, for instance because you have complex Linq queries returning geographic location information from which you wish to construct positions, I note that your constructor actually iterates through the Enumerable three times, once for each call to ElementAt().  This could cause performance problems precisely in cases where you are using complex enumerators.  The following slightly opaque code avoids that problem and also throws an ArgumentException when given insufficient data:

```
public class Position
{
    public double lat, lon, elev;

    public Position(IEnumerable<double> coords)
    {
        if (coords == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        using (var enumerator = coords.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (enumerator != null && enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                this.lat = enumerator.Current;
                if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    this.lon = enumerator.Current;
                    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        this.elev = enumerator.Current;
                        /*
                        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                        {
                            // What to do here??  throw an exception?
                            throw new ArgumentException();
                        }*/
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Up to you whether you throw an exception for too much data.

Hope that helps.